# Кот лёг на сюда / насюда

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Идём-ка через туда / черезтуда / черестуда.`

`Вставьте часть мозаики в сюда / всюда.`

`Кот лёг на сюда / насюда.`

`Мы черессюда / через сюда / черезсюда пошли.`

Comment: Надо так: сюда — (во что?) в сюду — всюду.  На что? - насюду. Через что? черессюду.  Классный способ!

Comment: Хороший вопрос, творческий. Чего минусовать-то?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слитный вариант странный, к тому же неправильный. Во-первых, ни в одном словаре таких слов **нет**, а во-вторых, можно от одной части задать вопрос к другой. А если задать вопрос можно, то пишем **раздельно**:

***Идём-ка через (что?) туда***;

***Вставьте часть мозаики в (что?) сюда***;

***Кот лёг на (что?) сюда***;

***Мы через (что?) сюда пошли***.

Да, вопросы могут показаться такими себе. Но тем не менее их задать можно — следовательно, слитный вариант неверный, к тому же выглядит как бред.

Comment: Вопрос-то  правильный... Кот лег на стул. Кот лег сюда. Кот лег (на что?) на сюда, насюда. Просто предлог перешел в приставку, что здесь особенного? Нет в словаре? Как у нас говорят, еще не успели внести.

Comment: Но это все шутки. При ответе надо понимать суть вопрос:  как образуются наречия (историческое словообразование). И говорить не про бред, а про то, почему нет насюду, но есть всюду.  Взять это слово за образец, рассказать его историю. Тогда это будет полезная информация.  Или вообще не отвечать (я так думаю).

Answer (score 2):

Кота я вёл черессюда,
Другой переградил дорогу:
Лежит он бок свой натуда,
И насюда, немного.

Когда повёл через туда,
А там другой - порогом.
Лижи́т мордóю на сюда,
И хвост вихляет рогом.

Коты, сказал им, вам намёк!
Ваш кот - свободный житель.
Чего лижи́те поперёк
И понавдоль лежите?

Коты сказали: ваш наказ
Мохнатым не наука.
Себя мы лижем напоказ,
Лежим - другая штука.

Comment: А вы поэт, оказывается... Голос от меня.

Comment: Грамотно хоть??

Comment: Это неважно. Но надо еще поработать над текстом. Я думала, что кот лежит так: один бок туда, а другой сюда.  Мой кот  так точно лежит, когда спит, и еще – лапа вывернута за голову. Лео зову (Леон). А потом уже – про "лижет" надо рассказать. Так смешнее. Ну и размер надо соблюдать.

Comment: Леоновых развелось.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос мощный. Пишем строго слитно, потому что в русском языке не существует раздельных словосочетаний "предлог + куда\туда\сюда", они все слитные:

```
Идем докуда? Досюда!
Он откуда? Отсюда!
Он тебе покуда будет? Посюда!
```

так что:

```
Идем черезкуда? Черезсюда!
Он накуда? Насюда!
```

PS Почему не существует раздельных словосочетаний, одна из причин, помимо наречности
[тут](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3181371-kak-pishetsja-pokuda-ili-po-kuda.html)

Comment: Все слова, приведенные в первом блоке, существуют во всех словарях (Викисловарь, «Грамота.ру»). А вот слов, приведенных Леопольдом, нет нигде, к тому же бредово выглядит. В первом блоке-то слова нормально выглядят.

Comment: Как говорится в словари просто еще не успели добавить ;) Вопрос-то о чем, что соответствует языковым номам словообразования, а что нет. Что в принципе возможно, а что нет.

Comment: А откуда вы знаете? Может, это просто непризнанные слова, поэтому и не добавили в словари.  ;)

Comment: Словообразовательная логика видна на примерах. Поэтому и знаю. Одно для языка естественней, чем другое, об этом и вопрос.